# How to style a treeview in Expression Blend

Tags: silverlight, treeview, expression-blend, blend

(Using Expression Blend 4 RC, Silverlight 3)

I have a treeview with several different item templates for different levels. When I open this project in Blend, it seems I can only really style the top-most DataTemplate (via right-click the TreeView in the Objects/Timeline view, Edit Additional Templates->Edit Generated Items (ItemTemplate) -> Edit Current).

How do I drill down into the level I want and edit those templates?

Rob

Answer (score 4):

A while ago I wrote a  [tutorial](http://www.timmykokke.com/2009/06/styling-a-treeview-in-silverlight-3-and-blend-3/) on styling a TreeView in Expression blend. Maybe it'll help.